# TabIndex is not working with toolStip in windows form

Tags: c#

After setting the TabIndex on ToolStrip and placed the ToolStrip Combobox, Button or any other ToolStrip control inside it, wont get the focused on Tab pressed. Hence ToolStrip combobox doesn't have tabindex property, I set the TabIndex to its container i.e. ToolStrip it self. However it never reach to it on Tab press.

Moreover If I will put Normal ComboBox inside it, Tab will be coming to it. Same behavior with other toolstrip controls is happening. How to get the focus on it on Tab press.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktkXq.png)

1. With Regular combobox, inside toolstrip, working fine.
   If I will place ToolStrip Combobox, it wont work. I am looking for this solution because there are many other places and toolstrip control in my applications and changing them is very tough task because this one is very simple, there are dynamic rendering is also happening and that I don't want to disturb. Please share some thought to solve it.

Comment: Toolstrip items march to a different beat, they don't inherit from Control.  They are window-less controls, they use the ToolStrip surface to paint themselves.  The ToolStrip.TabStop property is False by default, the user normally uses the mouse to active the items.  Set it to True and you can now tab to it.  And use the cursor keys to move between the items.  When you use a combobox then you'll probably find out why TabStop has that default.

Comment: Thanks Hans, As I tried this with other ToolStrip in my form and it's not working there. However in this it is working. But still not sure why its not working for all the places where ever I've toolstrip control on forms.